# Duplicate protocol definition 

Tags: iphone, ios4

Getting warning message that Duplicate protocol definition of ModalViewDelegate is ignored

Defined protocol in modalviewcontroller.h file

```
@protocol ModalViewDelegate;
-(void)dismissView:(id)sender;  
@interface Modalviewcontroller : UIViewController 
{
 id<ModalViewDelegate>delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<ModalViewDelegate>delegate;
@end
```

In the Modalviewcontroller.m file synthesize delegate

In Mainviewcontroller.h file

```
@protocol ModalViewDelegate 
-(void)didDismissModal:(id)sender;
@end
@interface Mainviewcontrollerontroller : UIViewController <ModalViewDelegate>
-(void)showModal:(id)sender;
```

In the Mainviewcontroller.m not synthesize delegate

Am I supposed to delegate in mainviewcontroller.m file too?

Why I'm getting warning message of duplicate protocol definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove `@protocol ModalViewDelegate;` in `modalviewcontroller.h` and import `Mainviewcontroller.h` in this file.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining the protocol twice one in mainviewcontroller.h and the other in modalViewController.h...thats why you are getting the warning...

Comment: Do you sure that syntax `@protocol … ;` is definition? I think it pre-definition and it says for linker - "You will find this protocol later, man".